# Highlight form border not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form:

```
<form id="shippingAddressForm">
```

When I click a button, I want the border of that form to turn red:

```
$("#shippingAddressForm").css('border','red');
```

However, my form's border doesn't turn red. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the form have a `border-style`? If there's no border, there's nothing to set the color of.

Comment: Can you include the `#shippingAddressForm` css in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `$("#shippingAddressForm").css('border','solid 1px red');`

Answer (score 3):

`border` is the CSS property for setting the width and style of a border. You want `border-color`. Make sure you've actually defined a border first too